# React.js cannot import js API library

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, webpack

New to JS and trying to code a simple reactive bootstrap app with React.js. I am having trouble with a API library, seems like cannot import it.

While test-compiling with webpack I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./~/steem/lib/api/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./methods in /home/james/Desktop/React-MessageBoard-master/node_modules/steem/lib/api
 @ ./~/steem/lib/api/index.js 33:15-35

ERROR in ./~/steem/config.json
Module parse failed: /home/james/Desktop/React-MessageBoard-master/node_modules/steem/config.json Unexpected token (2:13)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:13)
```

I succesfully installed the API library via npm, and now can be found within `node_modules`.

Then, I import my library via index.js by using import command.

Below my index.js:

```
import 'core-js/fn/object/assign';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/Main';
import steem from 'steem'
// Render the main component into the dom
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

and webpack.config.js:

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const args = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));

// List of allowed environments
const allowedEnvs = ['dev', 'dist', 'test'];

// Set the correct environment
let env;
if (args._.length > 0 && args._.indexOf('start') !== -1) {
  env = 'test';
} else if (args.env) {
  env = args.env;
} else {
  env = 'dev';
}
process.env.REACT_WEBPACK_ENV = env;

/**
 * Build the webpack configuration
 * @param  {String} wantedEnv The wanted environment
 * @return {Object} Webpack config
 */
function buildConfig(wantedEnv) {
  let isValid = wantedEnv && wantedEnv.length > 0 && allowedEnvs.indexOf(wantedEnv) !== -1;
  let validEnv = isValid ? wantedEnv : 'dev';
  let config = require(path.join(__dirname, 'cfg/' + validEnv));
  return config;
}

module.exports = buildConfig(env);
```

EDIT: There is a methods.json in the API library, found here:

```
/home/james/Desktop/React-MessageBoard-master/node_modules/steem/lib/api
```

I thought this might be the root cause...
Any help is welcome!

Comment: We need far more information than that to diagnose. Webpack Config, Package.json. Index.js.....

Comment: ```import steem from 'steem';``` maybe?

Comment: @matt93 already tried, same error...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Module parse failed with webpack and react, even using babel-loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34436690/module-parse-failed-with-webpack-and-react-even-using-babel-loader)